# How to extract array value in while loop from mysql database

Tags: php, arrays

how to get value in the array and extract in while loop 
below write few line code please help

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$view = $result->fetch_assoc() 
$arrrrrrr = $view['quiz_que'];
    $arraysss = [$arrrrrrr];                
    print_r($arraysss);
```

> Ourput Array ( [0] => A1,F2,3,4,S5,6,7,816,17 )

what I want

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
print_r($a);
```

> Output Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )

Comment: use explode() to extract it, Please do little research on google so you can get your answers soon

Comment: What is this string `A1,F2,3,4,S5,6,7,816,17` ?how do you want to get array of 4 element from it? I found your question hard to understand - please try explain better what you want

Comment: we want output like this 
Array
(
    [0] => A1
    [1] => F2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => S5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 816
    [8] => 17
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$arrrrrrr = $view['quiz_que'];//A1,F2,3,4,S5,6,7,816,17
$quiz_queArray = explode(',',$arrrrrrr);
echo'<pre>';print_r($quiz_queArray);die;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A1
    [1] => F2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => S5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 816
    [8] => 17
)
```

Comment: output = Array ( ) value missing

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to say?